# Flash AS3 Coloring Book - Movieclip only clickable in certain spots (Event Listeners)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, addeventlistener, depth

I am working on a coloring book and have a movieclip (outlines) containing many movieclips that can be changed to whatever color the user has selected. However it seems like some of the movieclips can be clicked anywhere and work great, and others you need to click a certain spot for it to color in.

I have an example here: http://jeffkilroy.com/hosted/softee/coloring.html

Notice the three sections of the icecream (top, middle, bottom). The middle is clickable from anywhere inside the movieclip, however the top and especially bottom require you to click on specific spots in order for you to activate the event listener.

Not sure if it is a depth issue because I would assume if that is the case it would activate at least a different movieclip but it just seems nothing happens at all.

Any help would be appreciated, I also have the source located here:

[Source CS4](http://jeffkilroy.com/hosted/softee/coloring.fla)

[Source CS3](http://jeffkilroy.com/hosted/softee/coloring_cs3.fla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It 's your custom cursor who take the event before the colorable things, try to add this code after your myCursor creation:

```
myCursor.mouseEnabled=myCursor.mouseChildren=false;
```